# 504 Gateway timeout Error when using SSL/K8S/fission serverless

Tags: kubernetes

The setup is in Google Cloud Platform.
Problem:
I will be brief:
- Running K8S cluster with fission serverless framework
- tested successfully (hello,world) with a LBR/K8S/fission
- Installed ssl certificate (used google certification prompts)
- Installed a HTTPS load balancer and mapped to K8S backend.
- WHen accessing https://, I get green lock, and cert details are correct. However, Hello world fails with 504 timeout error.

Seems issue is with handoff from LBR to K8s cluster node ..

Please help

Ganesh